# Importing a Pakage on Pycharm from the internet

Tags: python, module, pycharm

Currently the pycharm program I am working has a colour pakage in its 1.5 form, however I found a better pakage online from the site:

http://colour-science.org/

I wanted to know how to add a pakage from my computer into pycharm?

Comment: You might want to read about Python's pip for installing new packages. It is usually as simple as `pip install some_package`. Add `-U` before the package name to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally python packages can be installed through the Python Package Index (PyPI) via pip.

If you check out their instaltion guide, it shows various options on how to install the package. http://colour-science.org/installation-guide/

It looks like as long as you have your venv set up, you should be able to open the Terminal (hover over the bottom left box) in PyCharm and simply paste

```
pip install colour-science
```

then hit enter, and it will install it for you into your virtual environment (or to the root python if you don't have one of those set up.)

In PyCharm you can also do this visually by going to the `Project Interpreter` page in the settings. `File > Settings > Project: > Project Interpreter` 
and hit the green plus button on the right hand side.

[image: pycharm pip install]

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to. this package is available on pypi, pythons package index (a website with a lot of python libraries). if you want to use this library in pycharm just follow these steps:

1) go to File => Settings

2) on the left side there are tons of categories. choose the one named "Project: [name]" (name is the name of your project)

3) press on "project interpreter"

4) on the right side there should be a green plus sign. press it.

5) write the name of the module in the search bar. press "install package".

6) have fun using the library!